# Installing QT addin for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2013

i spent a lot of time trying to get these to install properly, so here i am.
I've already googled my problem countless times in different forms and still can't resolve it.
It's just very confusing because there are so many versions out there, and i don't even know how to build the binaries, if even have to do that, and i couldn't find the configure.exe. I don't have it after i installed QT5.

I have python, perl, Visual Studio, QT5,QT addin, and openssl installed.

When going to QT5, QT Options, then Add,  add: C:\Qt\5.2.1\mingw48_32 as the path and got an error about qmake not found or something.
So I deleted libqtmain.a and libqtmaind.a as suggested by some site and that solved the problem.

I've also tried this: http://blog.kikicode.com/2011/09/qt-version-uses-unsupported-makefile.html
but i couldn't find the Trolltech folder, so i stopped.

But now my problem is this

"This QT version uses an unsupported makefile generator (used: MINGW, supported: MSVN.NET, MSBUILD).

I don't even have a configure.exe file, and can't launch it from the visual studio command line.

I really have no idea what to do. I've been attacking this problem for all of yesterday, and i've ran out of steps today. Please help me.

I don't have the express version of VS. Just so you know.

Answer (score 4):

I just solved this issue. It get me mad, but is easy.
The Add-in looks to $(QTDIR)\mkspecs\default  to know which one to use. The "default" folder is not created after configure and build Qt.
So the way I solved is to copy&paste the "win32-msvc2013" folder as "default".
And now the Add-in recognised Qt.

BTW, after build the sources "nmake", I make an install of them in another folder so I have just the binaries and tools but not all the source that I don't need for develop software based on Qt.
Once the compilation is complete, then type:
    Set the root where the installation will be, ex:
        set INSTALL_ROOT=\Sw\Qt\qt-4.8.5-install
    Execute in your source's root the command:
        nmake install

Answer (score 1):

So after trying everything i decided to run compile the binaries.
I think not a lot of people have this problem and there is no solution on the internet because the 2013 addin is very new. So here is what i did, and what worked for me, after countless hours of trying.

I downloaded the zip located under the main downloads on their webpage: http://qt-project.org/downloads

I uninstalled the old QT. (kept the addin)
I unzipped the zip it into a folder i named QT at C:\
Then i ran the configure.bat located inside.
On the Visual Studio cmd i cd to the C:\QT\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.2.1 
directory where the configure file is,
Tried running the 'configure' file, there was no configure.exe. Then i ran 'nmake', that took like three hours.
The i went into C:\QT\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.2.1\qtbase\qmake
and made a folder bin where i copied the qmake.exe found in that same folder.
Finally i went into the VS addin, qt, qt options and i added that directory.
And it works!

Comment: Thanks for this info!  I'm still hesitant and wondering why Qt hasn't officially supported Visual Studio 2013 yet.  I'm particularly nervous that Qt is losing its desktop focus and the whole Qt Quick and QML direction has stretched the Qt team too thin.  Is your setup still working for you in mid-2014?  Thanks @user183180.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Qt 5.6, msvc2014, but had the same issue at first. This issue was solved for me by updating to Add-in 1.2.5 without changing anything else.